# why run time error is coming in my code?

Tags: c++

My code is :

```
int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while(t--){

        int ladder,snake,temp,x,y;
        cin >> ladder;
        vector<vector<int> >ar(ladder,vector<int> ());
        for(int i=0;i<ladder;i++){
            cin >> x >> y;
            ar[x].push_back(y);
        }
                cin >> snake;
        for(int i=0;i<snake;i++){
            cin >> x >> y;
            ar[x].push_back(y);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If i give input

```
2
3
32 62
42 68
12 98
7
95 13
97 25
93 37
79 27
75 19
49 47
67 17
4
8 52
6 80
26 42
2 72
9
51 19
39 11
37 29
81 3
59 5
79 23
53 7
43 33
77 21
```

run time error is coming and saying bad memory management. what's wrong in my code?

Comment: vector<vector<int> >ar(ladder,vector<int> ()); --> What does this mean? Is it a function call or variable 'ar' declaration?

Comment: You initialize `ar` with three elements, so why do you expect that you can access an element at an index larger then `2`?

Answer (score 1):

You'll see the problem already after the data sequence

```
2
3
32 62
```

The first value will be absorbed by `cin >> t` and can for this purpose be disregarded.

The second value is absorbed by `cin >> ladder` and results in `ar` being allocated as a vector of 3 int vectors.

The third row will be absorbed by `cin >> x >> y` and will be used to index inside ar as `ar[x].push_back(y)`. Since `x >= 3` which is the size of `ar`, you'll write to unallocated memory which will later result in a crash.

The code compiled with `g++ -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -g -Wall test.cpp` will also output;

```
/usr/include/c++/4.9/debug/vector:357:error: attempt to subscript container
    with out-of-bounds index 32, but container only holds 3 elements.
```

Answer (score -3):

Joachim Isaksson provides a good answer, but the issue seems to be running deeper than so. While trying to figure out what happens, I ran upon this magic fix. Open your main loop like so:

```
int main() {
    int t;
    cout << "This is a fix. Crazy, huh?\n";
    cin >> t;
```

I can honestly not tell you what is happening but this one call to cout stopped the program from segfaulting on my machine. Every. Single. Time.

Comment: Writing out of bounds is (according to the C++ spec) undefined behavior, which allows it to have any effect up to and including... working fine :) Mostly, you're not that lucky though.